# Redirect subdomain to a specific file instead of a folder

Tags: .htaccess

suppose i have a file like this on my site:

```
example.com/pages/live_report.php
```

and now i want when a user typed url **live.example.com**, it refer to above file without i to be force rename it.

how can i do that via htaccess ?

of course i try this rule that is recommended on [Redirect a subdomain to a directory using .htaccess](http://www.scriptygoddess.com/archives/2007/06/13/redirect-a-subdomain-to-a-directory-using-htaccess/) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/live_report.php$1 [L]
```

but this do not work

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't work at all, you many not have 'AllowOverride All' in the vhost file. Try something like

```
deny from all
```

to see if .htaccess is being processed

If you're getting redirected to `http://live.example.com/pages/live_report.php` you need to use a full URI, eg

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/pages/live_report.php$1 [L]
```

Comment: i do not want redirect live.example.com to that file just it is a rewrited url for http://live.example.com/pages/live_report.php however i test you rule in chrome  but show not found error

Comment: yes it is correct. but a note:Already when i create a new sub domain via cpanel this message is shown and after A few hours it was correct and work fine. Is it possible that it Is caused this problem

Comment: of course, it takes a few hours for the new DNS record to propagate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help (not tested):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder http://www.mydomain.com/file.html
```

or this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/file.html
```

Comment: but when you have the sub domain, it has a landing directory? Put .htaccess there